# RewriteRule in .htaccess and Reverse Proxy

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, redirect, cloudflare

Here is my problem, I`m struggling with it for a few days.

We`ve got a domain firstpart.maindomanin.com nad subdomain secondpart.maindomain.com.
Under first domain there is a first part of the project (based on SaaS commerce) and second part (under secondpart.maindomain.com) - based on Symfony. Those two parts are connected through SOAP services etc.

For firstpart.maindoman.com we are using Cloudflare. 
We`ve got reverse proxy so: 
firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/made is pointed to secondpart.maindomain.com/uk

and now (we cant enable cloudflare secondpart.maindomain.com due to some unrelated issues) we want to redirect all url-s from secondpart.maindomain.com/uk to firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/made
so for example
secondpart.maindomain.com/uk/furniture to firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/made/furniture
secondpart.maindomain.com/uk/sales to firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/made/sales
etc.
so we need to change domain and add 'made' between language code and rest of url

Other than that we need to redirect all urls like 
firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/furniture to firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/made/furniture
(add 'made' between language code and rest of url)

and we need to do it in htaccess under subdomain secondpart.maindomain.com.

I came up with something with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secondpart.maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})(.*)$ http://firstpart.maindomain.com/$1/made$2 [R=301,L]
```

and for url like 
secondpart.maindomain.com/uk/furniture

I`m getting redirection to

http://firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/made/furniture

which is fine but after redirection there is infinite loop (so except changing urls is not working)

As it turned out HTTP_HOST for both firstpart.maindomain.com/uk/made and secondpart.maindomain.com/uk is the same and it is secondpart.maindomain.com so condition is not working. 
I came up also with condition like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^made [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})(.*)$ http://firstpart.maindomain.com/$1/made$2 [R=301,L]
```

so condition is not met if there is a word 'made' inside URI and in this case it is the same as in first rule.

I tried several different configurations but nothing is working.

When i tested it with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ everything was fine and there was not redirection.

So im assuming there is something with reverse proxy on cloudflare.

Im not an expert in htaccess but really i tried a lot of solutions and nothing is working.

I would really appreciate some help with it.

P.S. Just in case here is a .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})(.*)$ http://vendauat.lauraashley.com/$1/made$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]


RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]



RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I suggest you obfuscate the client URLs

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^made [NC]
```

will always be met because your regex pattern says: if the request never **starts** with `made`, but the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable **always starts with** `/`. Maybe what you want is this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]+/made/
```